# AWS EC2 instance LocalDateTime not in line with system date

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, java-time

Here's my Java code in the main function of my Maven project.

```
LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(localNow);
```

When I run Maven install to create the jar, the output on my local machine is

```
2016-10-05T12:21:17.646
```

and when I run

```
date
```

on the command line on my local machine I get

```
Wed Oct  5 12:21:17 EDT 2016
```

Which is how it should be working. However, when I upload to my EC2 instance the output of the code is

```
2016-10-05T16:23:17.897
```

(I'd imagine this is UTC Time) when

```
date
```

in the console comes up with

```
Wed Oct  5 12:23:17 EDT 2016
```

I followed this guide to change the time on my EC2 instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#change_time_zone. It obviously works for getting the date from the command line, but LocalDateTime in Java does not agree. I'm using java.time.*.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalTime.now()` uses the default timezone of the JVM - details of how it's obtained are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--). So for some reason the timezone of your JVM is not the same as your OS's. You can force the timezone by using the following JVM option:

```
-Duser.timezone=America/New_York
```